# What's the best way to retrieve today's tasks from Asana?

Tags: asana

I am trying to pull up a page that shows all the tasks that are assigned to me and that are marked as today.

```
gem 'asana', git: 'https://github.com/phcyso/asana.git'

//assume w is a valid workspace
@tasks1 = w.tasks(Asana::User.me.id)
<% @tasks.each do |t2| %>
    <% if t2.assignee_status == "today" and t2.completed == false %>
        <li class="list-group-item"><%=t2.name%></li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The issue is that this is waaaaaay to slow since it iterates through my entire task list to find what's undone and marked as today. Is there a better way to do this? Couldn't find any API that would give me that data pre-filtered.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot currently filter on the server based on all of your criteria, but you can filter out completed tasks by specifying the `completed_since=now` query parameter. This will indicate it should only return tasks that have been completed after the current time, i.e. no complete tasks.

See https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks#query for more options.

Assuming completed tasks are the majority of your assigned tasks, that should help considerably.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I abandoned the asana gem and used httparty to go straight to the API and now it works great.

Comment: You may be interested to know that a first-party Ruby client for the Asana API is in the works. Look out for it soon, hopefully it will make your development even easier.

Comment: I would like to see improvements to the API (ie this feature, among others) before first party gems and interfaces. ... oauth2 and rest api's are simple enough that as a developer you shouldnt really need a wrapper, however you do need the api to return the results you really want ...  @GregS

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Agreed that first and foremost the API must be functional. We could be a lot better about search, and improving searchability is on our roadmap though I can't promise any timeline. Generally, we have a lot more things we could do than resources to do it with, and we definitely take feedback from the community into account when prioritizing. We'd love to speak with you more about this, so please drop us a note at api-support@asana.com so we can stay in touch. Thanks!

Comment: @GregS even better I made an asana task :P